# Issue with getting the URL of an image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to set the icon of a JButton but I can't seem to get the url of my image, keeps on giving me a null pointer. I was using the absolute location of the image, but since I am planning to export it as a runnable JAR I need it to be in the source file.

This is my build path:
[Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkAPI.png)

And this is the part of the code that is giving me a null pointer:

```
public void loadLogo() {
    logo = new JLabel();

    // ---- This line ---- //
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/Back.png"));


    Image img = icon.getImage();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200, null);
    icon = new ImageIcon(bi);
    logo.setIcon(icon);
    logo.setBounds(220, -20, 400, 800);
    add(logo);
}

// getClass().getResource("/res/Back.png") <-- is a null URL object
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, I'd start by using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/Back.png"))` and see if it throws an `IOException` and/or check the return result of `getClass().getResource("/res/Back.png")`, if it is `null` it's because the resource can't be found. You would then need to start investigating why that is, maybe export it the project as a Jar and see if the images are been included in the resulting jar

Answer (score 1):

Resource loading is always a little tricky to wrap your head around (as evidenced by my poor initial answer). The key things to remember is that resources are loaded *relative to the classpath*, and that the methods on `Class` are *relative to the current package*. Furthermore, `Class` supports paths starting with `/` to mean "from the classpath root" while `ClassLoader` does not.

Here's some examples. Consider the following project:

```
$ find *
java
java/a
java/demo
java/demo/a
java/demo/Demo.java
java/res
java/res/a
res
res/a
res/b

$ cat java/demo/Demo.java
package demo;

public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("System CL:\t"  + ClassLoader.getSystemResource(args[0]));
    System.out.println("Demo CL:\t"    + Demo.class.getClassLoader().getResource(args[0]));
    System.out.println("Demo Class:\t" + Demo.class.getResource(args[0]));
  }
}
```

Notice there are `a` resources all over. If we try to load `a` we get different results depending on how we get the resource.

```
$ java -cp 'java;res' demo.Demo a
System CL:      file:/tmp/java/a
Demo CL:        file:/tmp/java/a
Demo Class:     file:/tmp/java/demo/a

$ java -cp 'java;res' demo.Demo /a
System CL:      null
Demo CL:        null
Demo Class:     file:/tmp/java/a
```

So the `ClassLoader` looks at the classpath, while `Class` looks at the package. With `/` the ClassLoader`doesn't find anything while the`Class`looks at the top of the classpath. Neither found`res/a`.

A `b` resource on the other hand only exists in `res`, so both `ClassLoader` and `Class` will find it, but in different places:

```
$ java -cp 'java;res' demo.Demo b
System CL:      file:/tmp/res/b
Demo CL:        file:/tmp/res/b
Demo Class:     null

$ java -cp 'java;res' demo.Demo /b
System CL:      null
Demo CL:        null
Demo Class:     file:/tmp/res/b
```

Your exact results very much depends on your project setup, and what's on your classpath. Your `res` directory is inside your `src` direction (which Eclipse usually copies over to `bin`), so it should be on the classpath, so `Class.getResource("/res/Black.png")` should work. Do you see your resources in `bin`? If you don't, that's your problem.

If you do see your resources in `bin` try printing `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` to verify it's including the directories you expect.

If neither of those demonstrate the problem try running `Demo` in your project and passing in different paths, see if it finds anything.

As a generally best practice I'd suggest moving `res` out of `src` and into its own directory on the classpath; this decouples your resource from your code. I'd also suggest using `ClassLoader`'s methods rather than `Class`, since the package-relative-or-classpath-relative behavior is likely more error-prone.

Comment: I tried /src/res/Back.png, and it still give me a null pointer. So I should move res to the top-level directory and then how could I refer to its url since it is on the top directory?

Comment: No, you should NEVER reference `src` EVER in your code, it won't exist once the program is deployed. Eclipse (and post IDEs) will establish a classpath base which includes the `src` directory as well as other resources directories you might included (within the project settings)

Comment: @fontquest updated my answer, sorry for the misdirection.

Comment: @MadProgrammer absolutely right; I was muddling resource-loading with Eclipse's working directory. Eclipse runs `java` from the project root, so *file paths* should be project-relative. Resources of course should be classpath- or class-relative.